# Submit drop down values into google spreadsheet with google script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have coded a script with help from several stackoverflow examples but I get stuck when trying to go a bit further.

It seems very straightforward but I cannot seem to work it out.

So here it is:
I have coded an HTML script that initiates a dialogbox with some drop down menus. The data in the drop down menus is dynamic and taken from a range in a spreadsheet. I want for users to open the spreadsheet, run the script and choose the options from the drop down values. These drop down values will be pasted on the same spreadsheet.

The bit I got working is that the code sees the values that need to go in the drop down box, illustrates that and that there is a submit box.

However, I cannot seem to submit the values onto the spreadsheet. Please could anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

**test.gs**

```
   function openInputDialog1() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Test').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Add Item');
}


function getMenuListFromSheet() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Part Names')
     .getRange(1,5,6,1).getValues();  
}

function getThicknessFromSheet(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Part Names')
     .getRange(1,5,6,1).getValues(); 
}

function itemadd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Part Names');
  var LastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(LastRow);
  Logger.log(form);
  sheet.getRange(LastRow+1,1,1,2).setValues(form);


  return true;

}
```

**Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p>List of parts:</p>

<select id="menu">
  <option></option>
  <option>Google Chrome</option>
  <option>Firefox</option>
</select>

<select id="thickness">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="select()">
<script>
// The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showMenu)
      .getMenuListFromSheet();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showThickness)
      .getThicknessFromSheet();

});

/**function showThings(things) {
 var list = $('#things');
 list.empty();
 for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
   list.append('<li>' + things[i] + '</li>');
}
}
**/
function showMenu(menuItems) {
  var list = $('#menu');
  list.find('option').remove();  // remove existing contents

  for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    list.append('<option>' + menuItems[i] + '</option>');
  }
}

function showThickness(menuThickness) {
  var list = $('#thickness');
  list.find('option').remove();  // remove existing contents

  for (var i = 0; i < menuThickness.length; i++) {
    list.append('<option>' + menuThickness[i] + '</option>');
  }
}



</script>
<script>
function select(){
var x = document.getElementById('menu').value;
var y = document.getElementById('thickness').value;

google.script.run
            .itemadd(x,y)

google.script.host.close();
</script>


</html>
```

I know that I am somewhere not making the connection between the script and the HTML side but fail to understand where.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the lacking bits from your code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sheetConnect()">
```

In your **.HTML** file:

```
function sheetConnect(){

   var e = document.getElementById('menu'); //choices are Google Chrome and Firefox
   var name = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; //get whatever the user selected
   google.script.run.writeData(name); //pass the value to Code.gs
}
```

In your **Code.gs**

```
function writeData(name){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //whatever your sheet's name
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,8); //assign position to column H row 1
      cell.setValue(name);        // write selected data from Dropdown named 'menu'
}
```

result:

[image]

Use the knowledge here to complete your project :)

Comment: Thank you for this noogui. Could you please show me where I have to insert the HTML code bit? HTML is completely new to me until last week so I miss a bit of knowledge on how the syntax works. Do I have to assign the function sheetConnect() in .HTML to a button id to eventually with an onclick event write the selection to the sheet?

Comment: instead of your select() method, use my sheetConnect() on your input tag.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gs before but from looking at other examples yours looks right, however, in the second line you have tml.Service instead of Html.Service, not sure if that will fix all your issues but that will break it.

Comment: Thanks, sorry that is a typo on my end from my script into stackoverflow. In my script it has the correct Html.Service in there. I updated it now